# Moodle, PHP and using external APIs

Tags: php, apache, moodle

I am new to Moodle and PHP, so I may be asking for the impossible or just the impractical.

I am wondering how I might go about allowing client applications (written, perhaps, in C++, Java, AS3/Flash) to make calls to Moodle's Gradebook module, for example.

Does Moodle run as a server or does it rely on Apache or some other webserver?

Any pointers to examples of this kind of thing, as well as advice on books for learning PHP, Moodle, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To avoid this question to be closed, I would suggest you to rephrase it a bit, so it doesn't go off-topic. Also, it's maybe worth to be split in more than one question.

Comment: what exact you want can you please define??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle is a mere web application written in PHP. It relies on Apache (or any other web server) to serve PHP pages.

You might use something like [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) to implement the communication between "C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, and OCaml".

Regarding PHP, start with the official documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Regarding Moodle, here is a list of available books:

http://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?id=7246

Have a look to "Moodle 1.9 Extension Development" to write your custom extensions (blocks, modules, assignments):

http://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?d=55&rid=3796

Hope this helps a bit.